# Set Firebase Authentification with password only

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I want everybody who has the right password to be able to change specific settings on my page. To achieve this my rules for Firebase look like this:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read;
      allow update: if request.resource.data.pw == "WordPass";
    }
  }
}
```

This works as intended but the problem is that ofc Firebase saves the "pw" attribute in the Firestore which then can be read by everyone....

How can I make Firebase to not store this specific attribute, but still keep a simple approach without email authentification?

Comment: Honestly the best & more secure approach would be `signInWithEmailAndPassword("editor@yourproject.web.app", "passwordhere");`

Comment: Yep that worked 